# En/Dequeue error occured when make CPU SRJF scheduling in Linux Kernel Programming

Tags: c, linux, operating-system, kernel, system

I want to make SRJF Scheduling source. But it doesn't work properly. Compile is OK, but I cant get the results I expected correctly.
How can I fix or modify? I think enqueue part and dequeue part has wrong.

```
struct sched_array {
  struct list_head list;
  struct task_struct task;
};

void enqueue_task(struct task_struct *p, struct sched_array *array)
{
  struct sched_array *new = (struct sched_array *) malloc( sizeof(struct sched_array) );
  p->array = new;
  new->task = p;
  list_add( &new->list, &array->list )
}

void dequeue_task(struct task_struct *p, struct sched_array *array)
{
  if (rq->curr = p)
  {
    rq->curr = NULL;
  }
  list_del(&(p->array->list));
}
```

Comment: Take a debugger and step through the code to see what it does.

Comment: Note that `new->list` is not initialized.

Comment: @hyumil Please provide [mcve].

Comment: It is always best to post your error codes, or the output you are getting that is not as expected..

Answer (score 1):

One problem I see here is,

```
  new->task = p;
```

You are assigning `p` of type `struct task_struct *` to `task` of type `struct task_struct`.

Notice `p` is pointer whereas `task` is not.

Maybe you meant,

```
  new->task = *p;
```

---

Nevertheless we need [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to fully address the problems.

Comment: And maybe OP should turn warnings of his compiler on!